# Chronology of proofs of cubic and biquadratic reciprocity laws

Tags: reference-request

I just want to check if anybody knows a website where one can find a chronology of proofs of more difficult reciprocity theorems (such as the cubic and biquadratic cases) similar to the (already existing) chronology of 246+ proofs of the law of quadratic reciprocity (here is a link: https://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/fchrono.html ). I borrowed franz lemermeyer's book on the history of reciprocity laws from a library, and this book does include an extensive list of references, but i'm unable to find many of the proofs which the book refers to.

So i'll be grateful for anyone offering useful information!